# Extract Data Between Brackets in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with data in below format

| COURSE |
| --- |
| [] |
|  |
| ["12345"] |
| ["12345","7890" |

I want to extract the data between `[]` but without `"`

So, my output would be in below format

| COURSE |
| --- |
|  |
|  |
| 12345 |
| 12345, 7890 |

I tried the below code which works fine for first 3 rows

```
 select   REGEXP_SUBSTR (COURSE,
                     '"([^"]+)"',
                     1,
                     1,
                     NULL,
                     1) from TEST;
```

But 4th row only results in *12345*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simple `translate`?

```
SQL> with test (course) as
  2    (select '[]'               from dual union
  3     select null               from dual union
  4     select '["12345"]'        from dual union
  5     select '["12345","7890"]' from dual
  6    )
  7  select course,
  8         translate(course, 'a[]"', 'a') result
  9  from test;

COURSE           RESULT
---------------- -----------------------------------------
["12345","7890"] 12345,7890
["12345"]        12345
[]


SQL>
```

Comment: Great ... Thank you so much .